# Allocator ran out of memory - how to clear GPU memory from TensorFlow dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, out-of-memory

Assuming a Numpy array `X_train` of shape `(4559552, 13, 22)`, the following code:

```py
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset \
    .from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)) \
    .shuffle(buffer_size=len(X_train) // 10) \
    .batch(batch_size)
```

works fine exactly once. When I re-run it (after slight modifications to `X_train`), it then triggers an `InternalError` due to an out of memory GPU:

```
2021-12-19 15:36:58.460497: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:457]
Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 9.71GiB requested by op _EagerConst
```

It seems that the first time, it finds 100% free GPU memory so all works fine, but the subsequent times, the GPU memory is already almost full and hence the error.

From what I understand, it seems that simply clearing GPU memory from the old `train_dataset` would be sufficient to solve the problem, but I couldn't find any way to achieve this in TensorFlow. Currently the only way to re-assign the dataset is to kill the Python kernel and re-run everything from start.

Is there a way to avoid re-starting the Python kernel from scratch and instead free the GPU memory so that the new dataset can be loaded into it?

The dataset doesn't need full GPU memory, so I would consider switching to a TFRecord solution as a non-ideal solution here (as it comes with additional complications).

Comment: Same as the given answer below, you can also try [this](https://www.kaggle.com/c/petfinder-pawpularity-score/discussion/286124#1575072) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a hard limit on the total GPU memory as shown in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth)

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)
```

Comment: Interesting. In the link, they say that `By default, TensorFlow maps nearly all of the GPU memory of all GPUs` — is it possible to "un-map" the memory on demand, after this is done so that we get best of both worlds?

Comment: i think this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031604/tensorflow-running-out-of-gpu-memory-allocator-gpu-0-bfc-ran-out-of-memory-tr

Comment: Yes, I knew about this QA but I wanted to avoid the TFRecords overhead for this, as the dataset in this case is less than the GPU memory available.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a garbage collection seems to fix the issue whenever it comes up for me without having to restart the kernel.

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```